# Why is Java program compiled by VSCode faster than one created by manually running javac?

Tags: java, performance, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I hava a benchmark program as follows.

```java
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n_iters = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        long tInit = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n_iters; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n_iters; ++j) {
                for (int k = 0; k < n_iters; ++k) {
                    if (i * i + j * j == k * k) {
                        ++c;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - tInit) / 1000.0);
    }
}
```

I put it under `src` directory. I compiled it by

```bash
javac src/App.java
```

VSCode Java extention also automatically created a working directory `bin` and compiled `App.class` under it.

Fist I ran `java -cp src App 1000`, it took about 1.8 seconds.
Then I ran `java -cp bin App 1000`, this time it took 0.56 seconds.

Does it mean `bin/App.class` compiled by VSCode is faster than manually compiled `src/App.class` ? My understanding is that Java compiler does not do any optimization. JVM JIT does it. So these different runtimes don't make sense to me.

Note that there no any other source files or data files in `src` and `bin`. Other than cmd arg, the program does not depends on any external data neither.

I tested under the following environment.

- OS: Windows 11
- JDK: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3.1+2-LTS-6)
- VSCode Java Extention (redhat.java): v1.10.0

[edit]

VSCode Java extention uses ECJ compiler.
https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2689

ECJ and javac compiles differently and for this task, ECJ did well. I'm still figuring out if I can get the same performance for this task with javac.

Comment: What happens if you change the order (so first run from bin, then from src)?

Comment: Javac doesn't really do optimizations (other than then things like including or excluding debug information like line numbers, etc), so I guess this is more likely to do with priming file system caches.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I ran both several times in many order. The results were always consistent.

- C:\Users\lucid\workspace\java_bench\java_bench> java -cp bin App 1000 -> 0.566
- C:\Users\lucid\workspace\java_bench\java_bench> java -cp src App 1000 -> 1.909
- C:\Users\lucid\workspace\java_bench\java_bench> java -cp src App 1000 -> 1.874
- C:\Users\lucid\workspace\java_bench\java_bench> java -cp bin App 1000 -> 0.586

Comment: Your question seems totally unrelated to the results you're showing. It's nothing to do with compilation. The program invocation is slower depending on the contents of the classpath, but you never told us the contents of /src and /bin directories. If one is vastly larger than the other, of course the results you see would be unsurprising

Comment: @Michael In `src` there are the source code file `App.java` which I showed at the beginning of question, and the manualli compiled `App.class` file by `javac src/App.java`. In `bin` there is only `App.class` which VSCode Java extention compiled automatically. No any other files at all.

Comment: I can reproduce this when comparing `ecj` compiled code with `javac` compiled code. You are right that there are no optimizations happening at compile time. There’s just a subtle difference in the loop compilation, one is combining a conditional forward branch with an unconditional backward branch whereas the other is combining an unconditional forward branch with a conditional backward branch. Shouldn’t make a difference when the runtime optimizer is fully working, but having the entire program in the main method hinders optimizations.

Comment: @Holger Thank you so much. I also find out that VSCode uses ecj. I still don't know how to modify the program so that ecj and javac versions run in a comparable time. Can you give me any suggestion? 

>Shouldn’t make a difference when the runtime optimizer is fully working, but having the entire program in the main method hinders optimizations. 

I moved the triple loop part into another function but nothing was improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code Java use ecj to compile the Java sources, which is a different compiler implementation from javac.

I think you can use `javap -verbose xxx.class` to check if there is any difference between the two compiled class files.